# Temporarily deleted answer missing from asker's inbox

Tags: bug, deleted-answers, global-inbox, undelete

I [asked a question on CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/680/how-many-edges-can-a-unipathic-graph-have) and [received an answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/685). This answer does not appear in my inbox. I never saw a notification, and as of now the latest notification from CS is

```
{"SiteUrl":"cs.stackexchange.com","FaviconUrl":"https://cs.stackexchange.com/favicon.ico","CreationDate":"17 hours ago","Url":"https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/641/language-of-the-graph-of-an-affine-function/667#667","Title":"Language of the graph of an affine function","Summary":"Hint:\n\n$53 \\cdot 100000010000000000 + 4 = 5300000530000000004$.\n\nSketch:\n\n\n  ! Assume $a$ has $n$...","Type":"answers","Count":3,"IsNew":false}
```

This answer was posted, deleted and undeleted while I wasn't online. I suppose the deletion removed the entry from my inbox. Then the undeletion should have recreated an entry but didn't.

Comment: We're 5 years later and the bug can still be reproduced.

Comment: I originally posted [this question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8458/146446) on Code Review because I thought it was a CR specific bug, but it seems to be the same issue as the issue mentioned in this post.

Comment: +1: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284339/287315

Comment: Fun. It still happens with the new inbox.