# Notification for deleted/undeleted answer

Tags: feature-request, answers, notifications, deleted-answers

I just had an odd experience on [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/12270/5822).

1. I asked the question.
2. Another user (Rathony) answered and edited the question. I got notifications on both of these.
3. Some time passed.
4. Another user, origimbo, answered, and I got a notification.
5. Another user, abelenky, answered, but I did not get a notification, nor did the answer appear on any refresh of the page done in the period between this step and step 9.
6. Rathony made a comment on the question referring to multiple "new answers" (i.e. origimbo's and abelenky's).
7. I refreshed the page multiple times, but could only see one new answer, and noted that in a reply comment.
8. Even after the reply comment was posted, I kept refreshing and could only see origimbo's answer (and Rathony's).
9. On a subsequent refresh a few minutes later, abelenky's answer appeared.
10. No notification ever appeared in my Stack Exchange inbox regarding this answer.

According to a comment that disappeared shortly after abelenky posted it, abelenky had posted his answer (and apparently Rathony then loaded the page), then abelenky quickly deleted the answer to make some edits before undeleting it again, after which point it was posted as a visible answer to the question, without notification to the question-asker.  The basic action here was that of posting an answer, though it easily could have escaped notice unless someone happened to be manually looking.

Should answer undeletions (especially answers the question-poster had no tracked interaction with) be notified in a similar manner to answer postings, as in both cases there is one additional answer posted to the question?