# No notification for new answers

Tags: bug, notification-bar

Today I got a new answer to my question: [‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​It's possible to create empty content fields - particularly question titles and bodies - on sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359283/386331) but no notification was sent to me. I discovered it because I got the comment notifications.

Nothing in my inbox too:

> [image]

PS: I got a notification for the one I got on 23 Jan: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359912/386331

Comment: Email or inbox notes?

Comment: @Ollie the inbox notes

Comment: Actually no, you're reporting it, can you test-answer one of my questions, then delete it?  I'll see if I get a note.  Here:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358382/notification-when-a-followed-post-is-deleted

Comment: Do you have anything skewed in [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current)?

Comment: @Ollie not really, I got the notification of all my previous answers and also the comments and other stuff (followed notification and so)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Temporarily deleted answer missing from asker's inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126658/temporarily-deleted-answer-missing-from-askers-inbox). If you look at your linked question's most recent answer's [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/360278/timeline), you'll see it's actually been deleted & undeleted twice. When it's deleted, the answer's notification to you is removed, and it's not put back when the answer is later undeleted. I had this same issue myself once.